# SQL2022CU2/5 DBCC CLONEDATABASE red-ink - ledger table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

```
DBCC CLONEDATABASE ( DevMain, Test ) WITH NO_QUERYSTORE, NO_STATISTICS
```

This gets me:

> Database cloning for 'DevMain' has started with target as 'Test'.
> Msg 13511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Specified object 'sys.ledger_tables_history_internal_history' cannot be used as history
> table.

Having searched for the entire text message, because it contains no DB reference, Bing results in zero hits.

My colleague ran an equivalent on a separate SQL2022 CU2 server, omitting the NO_QUERYSTORE and has the exact error.

Is this a SQL2022 bug?  Or does someone recognize it and has a workaround/setting change, please?

**Apologies: CU5 is present.  Titled CU2/5 as it's present in old and current CUs.  We have not knowingly "turned on" any ledger feature.  If it is enabled by someone trying a CREATE TABLE and DROPping it later, that may explain, but it is not in the product we sell.**

Answer (score 1):

Overall CloneDatabase isn't supported for ledger databases. Interestingly enough, setting `LEDGER=ON` still allows the cloning to run and work. Once you have a ledger *table* though, supportability errors pop up. Most likely a missed scenario.

> Msg 12631, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> DBCC CLONEDATABASE is not supported for databases that contain ledger tables.

The below specifies a table that holds the history of actions for ledger, so ledger is enabled on this database and there were, at some point in time, ledger tables.

> Specified object 'sys.ledger_tables_history_internal_history' cannot be used as history table.

[sys.ledger_tables_history_internal_history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-ledger-table-history-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Captures the cryptographically protected history of operations on ledger tables: creating ledger tables, renaming ledger tables or ledger views, and dropping ledger tables.

If anything, I would say it's a combination of a few missed scenarios for checking supportability (and properly erroring) resulting in a different error. Most likely will require a code change.

### For Funsies

I created some ledger tables and then dropped them, hoping I'd get the same error as you did if I bypassed the validation checks in CloneDatabase. Sadly, I did not get the same erorr, it ran successfully on the ledger database. Note that this is *clearly* not supported and I had to edit the running code in memory to bypass the safety checks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Case Added - thanks for the link. https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/20f9d6a8-8c26-ee11-a81c-000d3a04ded5

Comment: It's definitely not a bug in general as it's clearly documented that ledger databases aren't supported. It is _probably_ a bug in the fact that it should error _earlier_ about being a ledger database.